# Rewriting rules in Apache to different port

Tags: apache, tomcat7

I am running two applications in centos 7. One is blog Which is running in apache server default 80 port and another one is Java application running in apache tomcat default 8080 port.

I have bought domain name (www.sample.com).
now i need to point www.sample.com to application running in tomcat port 8080 then need to point blog www.sample.com/blog to blog running in apache port 80.

what kind of rewrite rule do i need to write in apache configuration..?